# Erased Application and Files from the launcher, how do I get them back?

Tags: 11.04, unity, lenses

Help! I deleted the application launcher in Unity, along with the Files and Folders launcher! How do I get them back?

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can remove those two launchers (which are called lenses) is to remove their packages.

You need to ensure that these packages are installed (use `apt-get` or find them in Software Center:

- [unity-place-applications](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-applications)
- [unity-place-files](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-files)

Then log out and back in.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1734534

and edit the same files to change `ShowEntry=false` into `ShowEntry=true`

Answer (score 0):

I had these disappear randomly when I was first using Unity. Log out/in solved it, but that's clearly not ideal.

I think you might also be able to solve it by hitting

```
Ctrl + Alt + F1
```

Then logging in to that terminal and running

```
unity
```

Answer (score 0):

And if none of the above works, you can reset all the panel icons back to "default" with the following: `unity --reset-icons`. You'll lose any custom ones you've added, but those can be re-added again with relative ease.